# Do the different wordings of the Great Weapon Fighting style printed in the PHB cause them to function differently?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, fighter, fighting-style

I had a question about 'Great Weapon Fighting' as it applied to Paladins, which lead me here: [Does Great Weapon Fighting apply to Superiority Die rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55538/does-great-weapon-fighting-apply-to-superiority-die-rolls)
During my research.  While the answer cleared up my original question, I have a follow up question.

**First, my question:** When rolling for Great Weapon Fighting style as a Paladin, does the differentiation detailed below mean I can continue to re-roll all 1's and 2's until I get a 3 or higher?

**Secondly, the differentiation:** I noticed there is a variance between the Great Weapon Fighting entry in the Fighter listing on PHB pg 72 :

> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can re-roll the die and must use the new roll, ***even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2.*** The weapon must...

Emphasis on the differentiation from the entry, of the same Great Weapon Fighting style, found in the Paladin listing on PHB pg 84 :

> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll. [missing] The weapon must...

This particular entry is missing the crucial *"even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2."*  This particular entry says, you may reroll any 1's or 2's and must use the new roll **period** .

This is more than likely a typo, as some do exist in the version of the PHB I have when it first came out.  If anyone has any errata/newer versions of the PHB and can see if the full entry exists under Paladin please let me know in comments or in your answer should you submit one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### No, you cannot re-roll until you get a 3 or higher.

You can re-roll once. There is no difference in meaning between the two descriptions. The first offers the rule:

> you can re-roll the die and **must use the new roll**

and then offers clarification of the rule:

> even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2.

The second offers the rule:

> you can reroll the die and **must use the new roll**.

with no clarification. The clarification is not necessary. The rule is clearly stated in both cases.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll see what other input there is before deciding but this helps.  I'm currently writing a macro for 3d8r<2 which auto re-rolls EVERYTHING that comes up 2 or under on 3d8.  I can't seem to find a way to get it to do just 1 re-roll.  So needed an interpretation check before I decided to rewrite the whole thing. :D

Comment: If you're using Roll20, 3d8ro<2 will only reroll once per die.

Comment: @Xanderh I think I <3 you right now.  I've spent several days reading over the roll queries and other wiki's on the site I can find, but nothing had a full comprehensive list I was able to find.  These new 5E sheets are amazing, so I'm trying to put them to their full work lol.  I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries. I only found out about that because one of my players told me about it. No idea where he found it, though...

Comment: @xanderh: For future readers, the `ro` thing is mentioned on the [Dice Reference](https://roll20.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037773133-Dice-Reference) page.